# How to set a standard mobile version of a website for every smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, css

my website ([www.sauleezy.altervista.org](http://sauleezy.altervista.org)) has an error that I can't solve. I set two different .css files, one for desktop, style.css, and one for mobile, handheld.css. In my index I set this code:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1121px)">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handheld.css" media="only screen and (max-width:1120px)">
```

and it works.
The problem is that if I resize the page on my computer I can see the right mobile version of my website, but if I try to visit it from my smartphone I don't know why but it doesn't resize the content in the right why as from the computer. I have the right view also on mobile only if I check on google chrome the option "Desktop mode". In this case I have not the desktop version but the mobile version as I see it form the resized window from the computer.
How can I solve it?
If you click on my website and try, I'm sure you can understand. I hope my explanation isn't too bad. I apologize in advance.

Comment: did you add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Yes, I update my question... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has a fundamental error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="icon" 
type="image/png" 
href="Images/Icon-SaulEezy.png">
<head>
```

You must implement `<head>` just after `<html lang="en">`, which is perhaps why your `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` is ignored.

Change it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="icon" 
type="image/png" 
href="Images/Icon-SaulEezy.png">
```

Then check it in your mobile device.

Comment: I didn't check it in mobile before this edit, but now it is perfect. I'm sure you haven't cleared the cache on your mobile browser after this change. Your index.html is cached by browsers.

Comment: I tested it in both Opera Touch and Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot?

Comment: What did you do? The coming soon button has just disappeared in both mobile and small window desktop.